# Skipping Game Window Activation as Play Button Pressed in unity3d

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, application-settings

Each play pressing; Game Window Always Activates.
is there a way to skip  Game Window Activation on Play Pressed in unity3d?

simply, I wantto stay in "Scene Window" and not to activatation of "Game Window" as I press play button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. If you want to keep your scene view open, don't have it tabbed with the Game view. Detach the Game View and either dock it somewhere else or just leave it floating freely.